# Infinite loop when reading file into base64 string within readFile callback

Tags: node.js, promise, base64, infinite-loop, readfile

As title says, my understanding is that the code snippet below causes an infinite loop or infinite string. I have a file object which is an instance of a custom MediaFile class and I use FileSystem's [`readFile`](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html#fs.readFile) method which returns void, but accepts a callback function in case we need to do something with base64 string that is stored within `data` variable.

```
import fs from 'fs';

@Service()
export class FileHandler {
    public async toBase64(file: MediaFile): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const filePath = "some/path";

            fs.readFile(filePath, {encoding: "base64"}, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                    return;
                }

                return `data:${file.getMimeType()};base64,${data}`;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I tried debugging the code and I figured out it returns base64 value correctly, but for some reason the code results in infinite loop. I assume it is something related to Promise handling and I would appreciate if someone was able to explain me what exactly is happening in the background.

I also managed to fix the issue by using this code instead:

```
//...

const base64String = readFileSync(filePath).toString("base64");

return `data:${file.getMimeType()};base64,${base64String}`;
```

However, I'm still curious to learn something about Promise handling that I might overlook.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You are not calling `resolve` from inside the `Promise` you are returning. Try replacing `return` with `resolve(\`data:${file.getMimeType()};base64,${data}\`)`. Not invoking `resolve` or `reject` from a promise will cause the Promise to remain `pending` and therefore, the infinite loop.

Comment: I've tested it now and it works. I remember I've tried it yesterday and it didn't work. But it was the end of the day and everything is possible then :D Thanks for the help @AbrarHossain!

Comment: So, `fs.promises.readFile()` already returns a promise.  Why not just use that and get rid of the `new Promise()` entirely?

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00, I was not aware of `fs.promises`. Checked it and it works too! :)